# php mysql not pulling data correctly

Tags: php, mysql

so i am trying to have a table show what hills have been ridden by bikers (getting ready for the MS150). my issue is that when a person clicks on the button to say they have ridden the hill ... it is only working some of the time. when they say they have done a hill, the button disables and they aren't allowed to push it again. but, some of the records aren't showing up correctly. here's my code:

html:

```
$get_hills = "SELECT * FROM hills ORDER BY hill_region ASC, hill_id ASC"; 
$run_hills = mysqli_query($con, $get_hills); 
while($row_hills = mysqli_fetch_array($run_hills)) {

$hill_id = $row_hills['hill_id'];

$get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user); 
$row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user); 

$get_ridden = "SELECT * FROM hills_ridden WHERE hill_id = '".$hill_id."'";
$run_ridden = mysqli_query($con, $get_ridden);
$row_ridden = mysqli_fetch_array($run_ridden); 
echo "
<tr>
<td>".$row_hills['hill_name']."</td>
<td>".$row_hills['hill_region']."</td>
<td>".$row_hills['hill_rise']."</td>
<td>".$row_hills['hill_length']."</td>
<td>".$row_hills['hill_avg_grade']."</td>
<td>".$row_hills['hill_total_points']."</td>
<td><a href='".$row_hills['hill_link']."' target='_blank'><button class='btn btn-inverse btn-xs'>Link</button></a></td>
<td>";
if($row_user['user_id'] == $row_ridden['user_id']) {
echo "<button class='btn btn-default btn-xs' disabled>You Rode This</button>";
} else {
echo"
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='hill_id' value='".$row_hills['hill_id']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='points_gained' value='".$row_hills['hill_total_points']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='".$row_user['user_id']."'>
<button type='submit' name='hill_sub' class='btn btn-inverse btn-xs'>I Rode This</button>
</form>";
} echo"</td>
</tr>";
}
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['hill_sub'])) {

$get_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user); 
$row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);

$insert_points = "INSERT INTO points (user_id, hill_id, points_gained, points_date) VALUES ('".$row_user['user_id']."', '".$_POST['hill_id']."', '".$_POST['points_gained']."', now())"; 

$insert_activity = "INSERT INTO activity (user_id, hill_id, activity_date) VALUES ('".$row_user['user_id']."', '".$_POST['hill_id']."', now())"; 

$insert_hill = "INSERT INTO hills_ridden (user_id, hill_id) VALUES ('".$row_user['user_id']."', '".$_POST['hill_id']."')"; 

$run_points = mysqli_query($con, $insert_points); 
$run_activity = mysqli_query($con, $insert_activity); 
$run_hills = mysqli_query($con, $insert_hill); 

if($run_hills) {
    echo "<script>window.open('record-hill.php?user_id=".$row_user['user_id']."', '_self')</script>"; 
} else {
    echo $run_hills->error; 
}
}
```

and here's the sql db file:

```
-- Table structure for table `hills_ridden`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hills_ridden` (
`ridden_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`hill_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ridden_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=33 ;
```

any help would be appreciated ... i have been trying different queries to make it work, but have been unsuccessful for the past 2 days :/ PLEASE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@maarten, thanks for your idea ... i tried/tinkered with it, it was giving me a little bit of what i needed ... but realized that the best plan was the simplest, thus I got this:

```
$get_ridden = "SELECT * FROM hills_ridden WHERE hill_id = '".$hill_id."' AND user_id = '".$row_user['user_id']."'";
$run_ridden = mysqli_query($con, $get_ridden);
$row_ridden = mysqli_fetch_array($run_ridden); 
$num_ridden = mysqli_num_rows($run_ridden);

if($num_ridden >= 1) {
echo "<button class='btn btn-default btn-xs' disabled>You Rode This</button>";
} else {
```

this gave me what i was looking for ... needed to just step away from it for a little bit and then look at it with fresh eyes!

Answer (score 0):

First a suggestion: Since your user_id is in session, there is no need to make it an input field. In the latter case one could change the form user_id value to make an entry for a different user. Instead in your code that inserts data, take the user_id from the $_SESSION instead of $_POST

(Edit: which I now see you do take from $_SESSION. In the code that handles, insert, there is no need to select from the user table based on the session user_id, as you only use the user_id from that table)

Then, you could try make one query instead of three, skipping the user table as a whole, as the user_id is in the session:

```
SELECT 
    hills.*, 
    CASE hills_ridden.hill_id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 AS hill_ridden
FROM hills 
LEFT JOIN hills_ridden 
    ON hills_ridden.hill_id = hills.hill_id 
    AND hills_ridden.user_id = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."' 
ORDER BY hill_region ASC, hill_id ASC;
```

and your button `<td>` could become something like:

```
if($row_hill['hill_ridden'] == 1) {
echo "<button class='btn btn-default btn-xs' disabled>You Rode This</button>";
} else {
echo"
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='hill_id' value='".$row_hills['hill_id']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='points_gained' value='".$row_hills['hill_total_points']."'>
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='".$row_user['user_id']."'>
<button type='submit' name='hill_sub' class='btn btn-inverse btn-xs'>I Rode This</button>
</form>";
} echo"</td>
</tr>";
```

This code is untested, and just to give an idea.